# Why can’t I buy items in the store

Tags: fallout-shelter

When I try to buy a lunchbox or some Nuka-cola. It says purchases aren’t allowed and can’t purchase this item right now. Why is this?

[image: Could not complete purchase]

[image: In-app Purchases are not allowed]

Answer (score 3):

The person in charge of your account has restricted it so it can't do any in-app purchases. If you are a minor, this was probably done by your parents so you can't accidentally spend thousands of dollars on in-app purchases. Nothing we (or you) can do about this.